# Are there existing declarative pattern matching DSLs for transforming sequences of compiler IR instructions?

Tags: pattern-matching, compiler-optimization, dsl

Recently, I have been working through a [compiler class](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6120/2020fa/) that has a number of lessons on different optimization passes (dead-code elimination, common-subexpression elimination, etc). The professor (big thank you for making the class videos public) has some highly readable [python code](https://github.com/sampsyo/bril/blob/master/examples/tdce.py) demonstrating the various passes which, like LLVM optimization passes, take a sequence of instructions and return another optimized sequence of instructions.

The question: Instead of writing imperative code to find and replace specific patterns of instructions, is there a common/popular declarative pattern matching DSL/function that could be used? If not, are there technical reasons why this has been avoided? I have done some digging and LLVM has some [functions](https://llvm.org/doxygen/PatternMatch_8h_source.html) for pattern matching but it seems more focused on pattern matching single instructions as opposed to sequences of them, though perhaps that is a misreading on my part.

Most people I know would prefer to use regular expressions engines to do find and replace operations on sequences of characters instead of trying to write the code themselves. Both because it less code for them to write and also it is harder for a bug to sneak into the implementation of the matcher. That said, I realize that matching patterns within instructions is a much harder class of problem than regex. A regular expression can be broken down into a deterministic finite automaton (DFA). Because the patterns of interest for compiler IR will depend upon specific destinations and arguments the language would likely be a context sensitive grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are such DSLs.

One is [Nanopass](https://nanopass.org/), a DSL built on top of Scheme. Another similar DSL is MBase, see an example [here](https://combinatorylogic.github.io/mbase-docs/lang0.html).

The idea behind such DSLs is that pretty much any compiler pass consists of a number of smaller passes, each doing its own simple thing. Therefore a path from a source language to a fully lowered IR consists of a large number of intermediate languages, with specific small passes in between. Every pass is as trivial as possible, and difference between languages in this chain is tiny.

You can also use generic term rewriting languages such as [Maude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maude_system)